# How to update Rows of a JDBC Read Only ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm hitting a problem when trying to update a ResultSet.
I'm querying the database via JDBC, and getting back a resultset which is not CONCUR_UPDATABLE.
I need to replace the '_' into ' ' at the specified columns. How could I do that?

```
String value = derivedResult.getString(column).replace("_", " ");
derivedResult.updateString(column, value);
derivedResult.updateRow();
```

This works fine on Updatable, but what if it's ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY?

**EDIT:**

This will be a JDBC driver, which calls another JDBC Drivers, my problem is i need to replace the content of the ResultSets, even if it's forward only, or Read only. If I set scroll_insensitive and updatable, there isn't a problem, but there are JDBC drivers that works with forward only resultsets.

Solutions:

- Should I try to move the results to an inmemory database and replace the contents there.
- Should I implement the resultset which acts like all my other classes: Calls the underlying drivers function with modifications if needed.

I don't want to use the resulst afterward to make updates or inserts. Basically this will be done on select queries.

Comment: What is the database and, maybe more importantly, what is the query?

Comment: How did you create the Statement or PreparedStatement; that is relevant for how the ResultSet is created.

Comment: db could be different, since this will be used in a JDBC driver that uses another jdbc drivers. Because of that the query is changing, the columns name contains the information about it's content, from there I know to modify the content.
I created a Statement, PreparedStatement class that makes a Statement/PreparedStatement to the underlying JDBC, and gets the result from there.

Comment: @BalazsGunics Show the code that you use to create and execute the statement.

Comment: It's no use, since this will be a JDBC driver, which calls another JDBC Drivers, my problem is i need to replace the content of the ResultSets, even if it's forward only, or Read only.

If I set scroll_insensitive and updatable, there isn't a problem, but there are JDBC drivers that works with forward only resultsets.

I'm trying to move the results to an inmemory database and replace the contents there.

Or should I implement the resultset which acts like all my other classes: Calls the underlying drivers function with modifications if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience updating the result set is only possible for simple queries (select statements on a single table). However, depending on the database, this may change. I would first consult the database documentation.

Even if you create your own resultset which would be updatable, why do you think that the database data would change? It is highly probable (almost certain) that the update mechanism uses code that is not public and only exists in the resultset instance implementation type of the jdbc driver you use.

I hope the above makes sense.

Comment: queries will always be selects

Comment: Like described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97339_01/doc/java.816/a81354/resltse2.htm#1018228)

Comment: Something like that, yes. But consulting the specific database manual would be the way to go. Was this the case?

Comment: One of the drivers that will be used doesn't support updatable resultsets, what i figured out is to create an in-memory database, and run a SCROLL_(IN)SENSITIVE query against it, with CONCUR_UPDATABLE to get an updatable resultset. However this is a big hit on performancy, so i should try to get resultset that are updatable from the Databases itself (if they support that) the in-memory thing just for fallback.
What do you think?

Comment: Assuming you create the in-memory database and manage to obtain an updatable resultset from it, you have to ask yourself this: Why would any update to the in memory db be propagated to the physical database and actually modify its data?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25701/discussion-between-balazs-gunics-and-dkateros)

Comment: Company proxy blocks the chat :/. I added to the original answer though.